# Make cd + tab colorized like ls color?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

To get `ls` colorized I set

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
```

but my `cd + tab` still has no colours for directories. How can I make it behave like `ls`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following in your zshrc

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "${(@s.:.)LS_COLORS}"
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Not the same colours as `ls` though